# Why cannot Fama-MacBeth regression identify a zero-mean factor with explanatory power?

Tags: factor-models, fama-french, factor-investing, factor-loading

Imagine a factor perfectly explain the return of all the stocks in a universe, and the factor has a zig-zag shape around zero (as shown by the image).

[image: The factor zig zag around zero]

Since the factor perfectly explain the return of the stocks, the gamma (fitted from the cross-sectional regression or second-stage regression) would be the same as the factor itself. If we perform t-test on the gamma, it wouldn't have significance. However, shouldn't Fama-MacBeth regression be able to find factors that have explanatory power to the stock returns?

**EDIT1**

Added x-y labels on the figure.

In this single-factor toy model, all the stocks have zig-zag return with different amplitude (higher beta stocks have higher amplitude).

Comment: Yes, Mr.  Hsueh, please clarify the meaning of the graph in your original post. As it is, with no labels, it is quite unclear.

Comment: I've edited my post to clarify my question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you, my interpretation of the chart was not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose all of the returns are excess returns. (Otherwise, make them.) You are testing $\text{H}_{0}\colon\ \gamma_1=0$ in $r_i^*=\gamma_0+\gamma_1 \beta_i+u_i$. Since the factor perfectly explains the stock returns, you would reject $\text{H}_{0}$ in each period. But since the Fama-MacBeth method looks at multiple periods at once and since $\mathbb{E}(\gamma_1)=0$, you would not reject $\text{H}_{0}$ overall. And that would be correct in the sense that the factor does not command a risk premium.

Fama & MacBeth (1973) write on p. 610:

> Equation (6) has three testable implications <...> (C3) In a market of risk-averse investors, higher risk should be associated with higher expected return; that is, $E(\tilde{R}_m)-E(\tilde{R}_0)>0$.

In your market the investors are risk neutral, as every stock has an expected excess return of zero (the factor has an expectation of zero, a stock $i$ has that times $\beta_i$). Thus the implication C3 that Fama & MacBeth employ in their paper does not apply to your case, so you cannot take the nonrejection of $H_0$ above as evidence against your one-factor model.

Comment: Not sure if I am answering your question, but I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Ah, so the significance of a factor in Fama-MacBeth regression depends on the time-horizon. In my example, the expected stock returns on a short time horizon would definitely not be zero, and the zig-zag factor would be significant

Comment: @ShawnHsueh, consider editing your post to clarify the issues questioned in the comments under your post. Thank you.

Comment: @ShawnHsueh, I had understood you correctly. My answer still applies after your edit.